# How can i get a function from a different class to call an object declared in Main?

Tags: c++

I am making a tictactoe game and would like the function for a player turn to access objects i declared in main and other functions how could i do that?

```
void Player1Turn::player1Turn() {

char num;
cin >> num;

if (num == '1')
{
    board[0][0] = { xo1 };
}
```

For example how could i get board to change the values of gameboard?

```
int main()
{

    Setup setup;
    Gameboard gameboard;
    Player1Turn player1turn;

    setup.setup();
    gameboard.printBoard();
    player1turn.player1Turn();

    return 0;
}
```

If this is not enough code I could provide more

Comment: You can store a reference to `Gameboard` in `Player1Turn`. However, think a bit more if that design is reasonable. To me, it looks like `player1Turn()` should be a method of some `Game` class. And that `Game` would have a `Gameboard` member.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a reference to the specific `Gameboard` as an argument to the `player1Turn` member function. So, assuming your `Gameboard` class has a `board[][]` member, it would look something like this:

```cpp
void Player1Turn::player1Turn(Gameboard& gb)
{
    char num;
    cin >> num;

    if (num == '1')
    {
        gb.board[0][0] = { xo1 }; // Exact code will depend on your "Gameboard" definition.
    }
}
```

And your call from `main` would be like this:

```cpp
int main()
{
    Setup setup;
    Gameboard gameboard;
    Player1Turn player1turn;

    setup.setup();
    gameboard.printBoard();
    player1turn.player1Turn(gameboard); // Argument is the Gameboard to work on.

    return 0;
}
```

There are many other ways to achieve this, though, but I can't really suggest anything more/better without more details of your various classes. Another way, as suggested in the [comment by Nico Schertler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59380398/how-can-i-get-a-function-from-a-different-class-to-call-an-object-declared-in-ma/59380527#comment104952871_59380398), would be to have the reference to `Gameboard` as a "data" member in the `Player1Turn` class and pass the reference in its constructor.

Feel free to ask for further clarification and/or explanation.

PS: Your use of the three names, "Player1Turn" (for the class), "player1Turn" (for the member function) and "player1turn" (for the specific object in `main`) is ***extremely*** prone to typing errors! You should *seriously* consider a better naming scheme!!

Comment: This would enable a player to participate in a [simultaneous exhibition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simultaneous_exhibition). :-)

Comment: @Ted - It would enable many things! But I'm not going to condone exhibitionism! 